# Where does Google Pixel take caller ID from?

Tags: android-11, google-pixel-4

I made an outbound call to a business today and the caller ID displayed was that of a completely unrelated business in a different geographical location (so would have a different (UK) area code).

Does Google perhaps pull this data from business profiles on the search engine and how can I report the inaccuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Phone by Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer) app (which is the default Phone app on Google devices) uses data from Google and its licensors.**

In the Caller ID setting (**Settings - Caller ID & spam**), Google put a disclosure,

> Data being used in these features is provided by Google and its licensors. [**Learn more about business listings data**](https://www.google.com/help/attribution_maps/).

The listed licensors are:

- France, Germany, Netherlands, Belgium, Denmark, Israel, Luxembourg, Monaco, and Morocco: Kapitol S.A. (trading as Infobel) (the "Infobel Content")
- Brazil: TeleListas S/A
- Turkey: Turkey Yellow Pages ([Yellow.com.tr](https://yellowpages.com.tr/))
- Kenya: Yellow Pages Kenya Ltd ([www.yellow.co.ke](http://yellow.co.ke/))
- Egypt: Egypt Yellow Pages Limited ([yellow.com.eg](http://www.yellowpages.com.eg/en))
- Saudi Arabia: Al Wahda Express Saudi Arabia ([www.daleeli.com](http://www.daleeli.com/ar))
- Bulgaria: New Europe Directories Bulgaria EOOD ([www.goldenpages.bg](http://www.goldenpages.bg/))
- Norway: Digitale Medier 1881 AS ([www.1881.no](https://www.1881.no/))
- Italy: SEAT Pagine Gialle SPA ([www.paginegialle.it](https://www.paginegialle.it/))
- Republic of Ireland: Central Index ([www.centralindex.com](https://www.centralindex.com/)) and YourLocal.ie, trading names of Touch Local Ltd
- Czech Republic: Zlaté Stránsky (ZlateStransky.cz)
- India: INFOMEDIA Yellow Pages ([www.yellowpages.co.in](http://www.yellowpages.com/)) and/or IndiaCom ([www.indiacom.com](http://www.indiacom.com/))
- New Zealand: Finda
- Slovenia: Monolit informacijski sistemi d.o.o
- Taiwan: HongKu Info Co. Ltd. [www.ipeen.com.tw](https://www.ipeen.com.tw/)

It is also mentioned that

> If you know that your business listing is supplied by [...] and you have any questions about it, you should contact them directly.

---

For data provided by Google, it should be possible to report them by finding the related business listing first, then following the steps on [Edit business information in Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7084895) or [Report data or content errors on Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088).